# LINQ join query on Access DB

Tags: c#, linq

I have a general understanding issue of Linq as it seems. I tried already to find the answer in other threads but was not successful.
Why does this query not work ? I have two tables: one with customer data, the other with order data and try now to join them. But it fails and I don't understand yet why ?  In my opinion it is done as in any other tutorial.

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> query = from cust_ in Cust.AsEnumerable()
                             join order_ in Orders.AsEnumerable() on cust_.Field<int>("ID") equals order_.Field<int>("Customer ID")
                             select new { customer = cust_.Field<string>("LastName")  }
```

This is the error meassge it throws:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<<anonymous type: System.Data.DataRow cust_, System.Data.DataRow order_>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Data.DataRow>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast ?

Comment: This is the error meassge it throws:Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<<anonymous type: System.Data.DataRow cust_, System.Data.DataRow order_>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Data.DataRow>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast ?

Comment: you can add information to your post also after you have posted it. Just click on [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62595878/edit) below your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your select is not returning a DataRow, it's returning an anonymous type.  Either drop the 'new' and return a string,

```
IEnumerable<string> query = from cust_ in Cust.AsEnumerable()
                         join order_ in Orders.AsEnumerable() on cust_.Field<int>("ID") 
                         equals order_.Field<int>("Customer ID")
                         select cust_.Field<string>("LastName")
```

or maybe better don't specify the type, instead try:

```
var query = from cust_ in Cust.AsEnumerable()
            join order_ in Orders.AsEnumerable() on cust_.Field<int>("ID") 
            equals order_.Field<int>("Customer ID")
            select new { customer = cust_.Field<string>("LastName")  }
```